# Downloading the html of a page using perl

Tags: perl

I am using the following code to get the html of a page.

```
 #!C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use WWW::Mechanize;
    my $url=$ARGV[0];
    my $mech=new WWW::Mechanize();
    $mech->get($url,":content_file" => "C:\\path\\www\\page.html");
```

The above code works fine for certain sites but others like wikipedia require an agent_alias to be added.
However whenever i add an agent_alias the page.html displays some nonsense.

```
$mech->agent_alias('Windows IE 6');
```

I have tried to add other aliases but it doesnt make a difference. What can i do to get the html(source) of all pages correctly.

Comment: You are damaging the Wikipedia project by crawling and cause them unnecessary costs, therefore Wikipedia's terms of use forbid crawling.  I refuse to help you get around the restrictions they have put up. Instead use [MediaWiki::API](http://p3rl.org/MediaWiki::API) or the [database downloads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download).

Comment: Wikipida was just an example. Even google doesnt work when i add agent_alias.( And crawling definitly isnt my intention.)

Comment: Guess what, Google forbids it for the same reasons. Use their [search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

Comment: FYI, programmamatically getting a page does not equal crawling.

Answer (score 1):

I had better experience with libwww-perl:

```
require LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
$response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/');
```